# How to right-align menu items in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

There is an open [Git issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/10749) requesting props for the alignment of Menu items. In the meantime, what is the correct way to move some Navbar items (eg Login, logout) to the right side?

Here is there example code for a Menu, where all Menu items are on the left side.

```
import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;
const MenuItemGroup = Menu.ItemGroup;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    current: 'mail',
  }
  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('click ', e);
    this.setState({
      current: e.key,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        selectedKeys={[this.state.current]}
        mode="horizontal"
      >
        <Menu.Item key="mail">
          <Icon type="mail" />Navigation One
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="app" disabled>
          <Icon type="appstore" />Navigation Two
        </Menu.Item>
        <SubMenu title={<span><Icon type="setting" />Navigation Three - Submenu</span>}>
          <MenuItemGroup title="Item 1">
            <Menu.Item key="setting:1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="setting:2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
          </MenuItemGroup>
          <MenuItemGroup title="Item 2">
            <Menu.Item key="setting:3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="setting:4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
          </MenuItemGroup>
        </SubMenu>
        <Menu.Item key="alipay">
          <a href="https://ant.design" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Navigation Four - Link</a>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try giving the menu items you want on the right `float: right` via JSX styling or a CSS class.

Example pulling the Navigation Three item to the right with JSX inline styling, `style={{float: 'right'}}`:

```
    <SubMenu style={{float: 'right'}} title={<span><Icon type="setting" />Navigation Three - Submenu</span>}>
      <MenuItemGroup title="Item 1">
        <Menu.Item key="setting:1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="setting:2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
      </MenuItemGroup>
      <MenuItemGroup title="Item 2">
        <Menu.Item key="setting:3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="setting:4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
      </MenuItemGroup>
    </SubMenu>
```

#### UPDATE: *(for Firefox)*:

If you have right *and* left menu elements, you need to add
`style={{float: 'right'}}` to the right `MenuItem`'s and 
`style={{float: 'left'}}` to the left ones.

Leaving out the latter will cause some browsers (Firefox) to render the underlying `<li>` tags with a break between them.

Comment: This results in the options appearing in reverse order for me when using the "horizontal" menu mode.

Answer (score 20):

Due to some change in Ant design 4.16.3, `style={{float: 'right'}}` won't work anymore.

Instead, you can use `style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}`.

Source: [Github issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/31097)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}`.

`marginLeft: 'auto'` didn't work for me because I needed to apply it to `Menu` rather than `SubMenu`

Comment: This works like charm. Float right also works but has bug, it cannot render the overflow of the horizontal menu. So this answer is best for 2023.

Comment: Confirmed, in 2023, this is the best answer

Answer (score 4):

None of answers work if you want to align several items left and several right.
To do so, add `style={{ display: 'block' }}` to `<Menu>` and `style={{ float: 'right' }} to <Menu.Item>` you want on the right.
Works for horizontal menu, didn't tried on vertical...

```
<Menu style={{ display: 'block' }}>
  <Menu.Item key='home'><Link to={'/'}>Home</Link></Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key='option1'><Link to={'/option1'}>Option 1</Link></Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key='notif' style={{ float: 'right' }}>
    <Link to={'/notif'}>Notifications</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key='logout' style={{ float: 'right' }}>
    <Link to={'/notif'}>Logout</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This will solve the issue:

```
style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68994581/2227743  no?